# How to proxy a varargs function in PHP

Tags: php, function, variadic-functions

I'd like to "proxy" a varargs function (kinda like a shortcut):

```
/** The PROXY function */
function proxy_to_foo(/*varargs*/)
{
    real_foo(func_get_args());
}

/** The real function */
function real_foo(/*varargs*/)
{
    print_r(func_get_args());
}

// Now I call it:
proxy_to_foo(1, 2, 3);
```

But I get this (obviously):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Whereas this was the intention:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

How to fix it? Some weird reflection magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `call_user_func_array`:

```
/** The PROXY function */
function proxy_to_foo(/*varargs*/)
{
    call_user_func_array('real_foo', func_get_args());
}
```

If your php is 5.6 and higher use variadic function arguments:

```
function proxy_to_foo(...$args) 
{
    real_foo(...$args);
}

function real_foo(...$args)
{
    print_r($args);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I want to call a method on the same object, I tried "call_user_func_array" with "$this->boo" as string (boo being the method name), but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: `call_user_func_array(array($this, 'real_foo'), func_get_args());`

Comment: Thanks. Really messy tho, but that's just the PHP's way.

Comment: In php 5.6, to proxy it, you need still to expand the array. so: `real_foo(...$args);`

Comment: Oh, that's a bit less pretty. But atleast less ambiguous than Java varargs, where array is auto-expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in this case:

```
function proxy_to_foo(/*varargs*/)
{
    real_foo(func_get_args());
}

function real_foo(/*varargs*/)
{
    print_r(iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(func_get_args())), FALSE));
}

proxy_to_foo(1, 2, 3);
```